# overflow-x:hidden - still scrollable in the x-axis

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have set the below div with overflow-y:auto because i want it scroll vertically, but not horizontally, yet it is still scrollable on mac osx and on chrome (even if the scrollbar is not visible) -- tested on chrome for android phone and tablet, try resizing the browser to see what i mean.

```
#outer-wrap {
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden}
```

Rest of code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xuHeD/

Comment: new css3 rules defined as viewport height - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Comment: i've never seen it used before, thanks for the reference, that's quite handy! :)

Comment: look here @flauntster 2nd answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window

Comment: I know you said this is happening on a mac, but just for info this is not reproducible on Windows using Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: did you use the middle mouse scroll? this was taken on chrome - windows 8 - image is here: http://i.imgur.com/YjhXECL.png